# Python: Selenium New Tab

Tags: python, selenium, tabs

I am using Firefox v67.0.4 with geckodriver 0.24.0 and I tried several methods to open a new tab, but the only thing Firefox is doing, is opening a new **window**.

Are there any other approaches to open new tabs next to these two:

1.)

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[tab_index])
driver.get(link)
```

2.)

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[tab_index])
driver.get(link)
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug with the current versions?

Comment: try using this instead: window.open('about:blank', '_blank');

Comment: This also opens a new window

Comment: there is an option in Firefox which might affect this... it's something like "Open links in tabs instead of new window".  That should be on by default... maybe check to see what this is set to when the browser launches.

Comment: @saitam are you getting the same action when operating manually?

Comment: @pcalkins: Thanks I checked it and default is set to `browser.link.open_newwindow = in tab`. @VardhmanPatil: Manually `ctrl + t` opens a new tab and `vtrl + n` a new window

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. this is the code I use to open a new tab and switch to it:

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
windows = browser.window_handles
time.sleep(1)
driver.switch_to.window(windows[tab_index])
```

but starting from Firefox 68.0 you also need to add the code shown here:

[How to fix Selenium Webdriver not opening a new tab on Firefox 68.0 and above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973213/how-to-fix-selenium-webdriver-not-opening-a-new-tab-on-firefox-68-0-and-above/56973434#56973434)