# How to fix Selenium Webdriver not opening a new tab on Firefox 68.0 and above?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, environment-variables

After upgrading to firefox 68 my selenium python script broke,
I wasn't able to open a new tab using the code that worked prior.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

my_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

my_profile.set_preference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart", False)
my_profile.set_preference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart.1", False)
my_profile.set_preference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2", False)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=my_profile)

browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Mozilla made changes to future Firefox versions starting firefox 68,

so changing "browser.tabs.remote.autostart” value to false, 
simply won’t disable e10s (Multi-Process)

and as a result won't open a new tab in selenium.

you can read more about it here:

https://techdows.com/2019/05/mozilla-firefox-68-doesnt-allow-turning-off-e10s.html

https://www.ghacks.net/2016/07/22/multi-process-firefox/

---

The solution is to delete the previous code and use this instead:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os

os.environ['MOZ_FORCE_DISABLE_E10S'] = '1'
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
```